# An urn contains 10 balls, of which 1 is marked

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

An urn contains 10 balls, of which 1 is marked, if 5 balls are drawn one at a time (without replacement) and in each selection there is the same probability in the remaining balls. What is the probability that the marked ball will be selected?

I'm starting to learn probability, and I'm trying to do exercises but I don't really understand how to get that probability.

If our experiment is to select one ball at a time. The first ball can be any of the 10 (including the marked ball), in the next selection it can be any of the remaining 9 (including the marked ball) and similarly for the remaining selections.

Comment: It might be easiest to calculate the probability that the marked ball won't be selected, then subtract it from one.  How many ways can you select 5 balls?  How many ways can you select 5 unmarked balls?

Comment: You seem to be selecting half the balls and all selections are equally likely

Answer (score 1):

Imagine that the balls are arranged in a line, so that the first five become the ones selected.   The marked ball may be in any place in the line without bias.

So...